# C# equivalents for JavaScript Cryptography API functions

Tags: c#, cryptojs

The new Cryptography API for Javascript has these functions:

```
window.crypto.subtle.sign

window.crypto.subtle.importKey
```

Please what are their equivalents in C#

Thanks.

EDIT:
I am asking for the c# equivalents of the JavaScript Cryptography functions implemented here: http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/

Comment: Can you please share which cryptography algorithm is included inside the cryptojs lib so I can then tell you the equilvalent in C#?

Comment: @CodingChief I'm referring to the JS functions implemented here: http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/

Comment: Great, then the link to MSDN I have provided is the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the equlivalents(most of them) residing in following namespace.

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
```

Here's a more detailed list of the available algorithms : [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I have found some of them , but in most cases i have to combine functions to get the solutions required. Thanks, i'll accept  this answer.